# What is the preferred PMI framework friendly - Web Application for Project Managers?

Tags: tools, pm-software, pmi-framework

#### Don't go answer the question before reading below

Many companies follow a very distinct business specific project management approach.  I am sure this is true for mid and big companies across the world.

Since most of the information is spread through the different departments, then, in matter of a few years you end up with one or many home grown project management applications to track different things.  To be clear, I am thinking of the PMI factors that everyone tracks.

- Projects
- Portfolios
- Programs
- Tasks
- budgets
- forecasts
- etc

So, I am interested in getting a good list of PMI preferred Web Applications that will allow companies to track the things above.

Thanks for taking the time in reading the post and giving your opinions below.

Geo

Comment: I don't think the PMI has opinions on software yet.

Comment: You are right, I was trying to obtain the preferred PM web application that follows the PMI Framework.  I think I have to re-phrase the question.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use CodeSpaces.com for managing Software Projects, It´s an integrated web tool that contains Agile Project Planning using Scrum, Code Control (Suvbersion or Git), Forums, Documents, Information Dashboards, CardWall, Integration of Subversion with tasks, integration of tasks with documents.

I find CodeSpaces.com very usefull, but this is for tracking software development, for planning I use the PMI Framework with a set of word templates and excel.

For estimation I use Function Points, using an excel template.

I think that the tools for planning and estimating are not important, but the most important is to have an integrated environment for keep track of the project, that is where most of PMs fails.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best things I've found is [Google Spreadsheets](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/spreadsheets/#utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-bk&utm_medium=ha&utm_term=google%20spreadsheets).  You can track pretty much anything just by customizing it to fit your needs.  It can notify people when changes are made to the document.  It's in the cloud, so it can be accessed from anywhere and is always up to date.  It also has an API so you can read the data and import it into another application.

You can create charts, use formulas to perform automated, complex calculations, and make educated, strategic decisions based on the numbers.